# My VB.NET solution does not contain a Main function

Tags: .net, vb.net, clipboard, program-entry-point

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235406%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

> Every Visual Basic application must contain a procedure called Main.

I... Didn't find such a method in my solution...

It starts from

```
Private Sub MyApplication_Startup( _
   ByVal sender As Object, _ 
   ByVal e As StartupEventArgs) _ 
       Handles Me.Startup
```

My [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8525139/clipboard-containsdata-and-clipboard-getdata) is, in fact, I try to follow a recommendation that says:

**Clipboard.GetDataObject** Always Returns null? 
If you find you're always getting null from GetDataObject, try adding `[STAThread]` before your static void `Main()`.

So, me, if I don't find `Main()`... I can't follow that recommendation in VB.NET...

Comment: "Windows Forms applications run on their own. However, the Visual Basic compiler automatically generates a Main procedure in such an application"

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever So, how can I set a `[STAThreadAttribute()]` to the main function?

Answer (score 4):

Firstly add .vb file in your project (say Program.vb).

```
Public Class Program
    <STAThread()>
    Shared Sub Main()
        Dim frm As New Form1
        Application.Run(frm)
    End Sub
End Class
```

and turn off - Enable Application Framework from [Project + Properties + Application], set the   start object - Program or Sub Main.

Comment: I can't do this... this is a big ancient solution, with tens of projects inside, and it uses the application events like Startup as specified above... it Saves My.Settings at shutdowns, Enable XP visual styles, so I am afraid I don't know how to replace all this.

Comment: @serhio I think that's the only way to set it.  See [STAThreadAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stathreadattribute.aspx)

Comment: @LarsTech I tried to `?Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.GetApartmentState
STA {0}`
so, apparently the current thread has already the STA state... Now I don't understand anything...